# Is there a way to get data of the first 3 rows of each group of rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ms-office, data-cleaning

I have data consisting of over 5000 rows in Excel. I want to get the first 3 rows from each group into a different sheet. If that is not possible, I would like to delete all rows except the first 3 rows of each group of data.

PS: I have searched for this question on multiple forums, and I did not get the answer. If you think this is a duplicate question, lacking the technical terms, please share the links to the discussions politely.

***Here is a screenshot of the data in Excel:***
[image]

Comment: You could just add a new counter column in F2 (then copy down) using something like `=IF(B2=B1,N(F1)=1,1)` then filter that column for values 1-3 and copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing it in Excel 365:

```
=LET(seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A21)),FILTER(A2:E21,seq-XLOOKUP(A2:A21,A2:A21,seq)<=2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 365, you could do:

```
=LET( table, A2:E26,
       rSeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS(table),,0 ),
       no, INDEX( table, , 1 ),
       fIdx, FILTER( rSeq+1, IFERROR(INDEX( no, rSeq+1, ) <> INDEX( no, rSeq+2, ),TRUE)),
       FILTER(table, MOD(rSeq,ROWS(fIdx))<=2) )
```

Where the table is located in this example in A2:E36.

[image: result]

If your data are not sorted by the number of votes, there is also a way to have the formula select the top 3 candidates based on votes - a little more complex, but also possible.